# Finding $ \int \frac{1}{(\sin x+2 \sec x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

Finding $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{(\sin x+2 \sec x)^2}dx$

Attempt: Assume $\displaystyle I=\int \frac{\cos^2x}{(\sin x\cos x+2)^2}dx= \int\frac{4\cos^2 x}{(\sin 2x+8)^2}dx$

could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: Anyway, through the substitution $x=2\arctan\frac{t}{2}$ the problem boils down to the integration of a rational function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$=2\int\dfrac{\cos2x}{(\sin2x+8)^2}dx+2\int\dfrac{dx}{(\sin2x+8)^2}$$

set $\sin2x+8$ for the first integrand

and use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) for the second as $$\int\dfrac{dx}{(\sin2x+8)^2}=\int\dfrac{1+\tan^2x}{\{2\tan x+8(1+\tan^2x)\}^2}\sec^2x\ dx$$

[Partial Fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) can come handy.